# gconftool-2 not working when run from a script

Tags: command-line, gconf

I'm trying to change the settings of gnome-terminal, using `gconftool-2` via. a bash script.
When I run `gconftool-2` commands from the command line, they work.:

```
gconftool-2 --set /apps/gnome-terminal/profiles/Default/background_color --type string "#393939"
```

In this case it changes the background colour of `gnome-terminal` - the change occurs immediately.
However, when I run the commands from a script they don't work.
The overall script runs as `sudo`, i.e. `sudo ./script.sh` then I use the `sudo -u` option to de-elevate back to the regular user. In this case `ubuntu` as I'm using a Ubuntu 14.04 live CD.

```
#! /bin/bash
sudo -s -u ubuntu<<-EOF
        gconftool-2 --set /apps/gnome-terminal/profiles/Default/background_color --type string "#393939"
        gconftool-2 --set /apps/gnome-terminal/profiles/Default/use_theme_colors --type bool false
        gconftool-2 --set /apps/gnome-terminal/profiles/Default/foreground_color --type string "#fff"
        gconftool-2 --set /apps/gnome-terminal/profiles/Default/background_type --type string "transparent"
        gconftool-2 --set /apps/gnome-terminal/profiles/Default/background_darkness --type float 0.860515
EOF
```

The above script runs without errors, and the targeted settings of `gconftool-2` **do get updated**, i.e. running

```
gconftool-2 -a /apps/gnome-terminal/profiles/Default
```

gives:

```
...
 use_theme_colors = false
 ...
 background_darkness = 0.86051500
 ...
 foreground_color = #fff
 etc
```

But `gnome-terminals` appearance doesn't change - even when a new instance is launched.
How can I fix this?

Comment: try script without sudo

Comment: do you mean try running script as regular user or remove  the `sudo -u` command from inside the script?

Comment: I no longer use gconf/gconftool-2 at all but if you run it as root then you're setting for root, not you (user

Comment: thanks, yes. I removed the `sudo -u` command and ran the script as the regular user - and it worked! thanks. The thing is I need to run the overall script as root/sudo  - and I thought `sudo -u <user>` has the same effect as if the script was run as the ordinary user. `sudo -u <user>` definitely works for other commands

Comment: `gconftool` needs to talk to the message bus, I think: probably that connection is getting broken when you use `sudo` (because of the restrictive environment). It *may* be sufficient to set the `DISPLAY` variable - or you may need to actually retrieve and set the `DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS`

Comment: @steeldriver thanks - thats interesting, I tried adding `export DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS=unix:abstract=/tmp/dbus-nvBo5mfMDH` to the script but it didn't work. I'm starting to wonder if this is why users like @doug and others don't use `gconftool-2` anymore!

Comment: belay that remark ! I stupidly put the `export DBUS` statement outside the `sudo -u` heredoc. I fixed and now it works! thanks @steeldriver - I never would have worked that out myself!

Comment: OK maybe you could write up a nice answer - to help others who may want to try the same thing

Answer (score 1):

The issue appears to come from the somewhat sanitized environment the `sudo` command runs in.
Even though the commands were being executed as the `ubuntu` user, the environment didn't contain the full complement of `env` variables usually present when using an interactive terminal / shell.
`gconftool-2` seems to need access to the `DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS` variable.  In this case I was able to pass it a value I copied from another terminal I was running. But if the script ran on another machine, it might need to fetch it dynamically, in which case something like the script below would be necessary.

```
# Grab the DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS variable from nautilus's environment
eval $(tr '\0' '\n' < /proc/$nautilus_pid/environ | grep '^DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS=')

# Check that we actually found it
if [ -z "$DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS" ]; then
#echo "Failed to find bus address" >&2
exit 1
fi

# export it so that child processes will inherit it
export DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS
```

Also, more info can be obtained if you google -  *gconftool-2 dbus_session_bus_address* as this seems to be a somewhat common issue.